# Arduino as serial 'snoop' tool for 77 bits at 100k baud?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

curious if a Arduino could be configured to read and serial print raw binary bits from a proprietary serial encoder used on machine tools and robots... if so, might have a lot of other possible uses.
 I made up a 120 volt servo drive for manually moving big fanuc machine/robot servos, handy during rebuilding/service to be able to move a axis without a control...but the older drives read 4 gray code channels kinda like a set of halls for brushless commutation...on the serial versions, same drive could move the motor if I could decipher the commutation bits and output graycode to the drive... a tiny Arduino looks like a ideal little thing to try doing this.

Scoped out the signals long ago, kinda know where the bits are, but need to be able to actually print them out thru 90 degrees of shaft rotation to find the 12 steps for commutation required by the drive.

Arduino is new to me, but in the past few days have been quite impressed with its abilities.
 If anyone can suggest a way for Arduino to read a repeating 77 bit data stream at ~100K baud, I'm all ears... I think a 'serial snoop tool' with easily changed baud rates(including non-standard) and 'word length', then serial print out could be really handy. to prevent overflow in my case, could only do the serial print every X milliseconds, and I could just rotate slow enough to get a decent sample.

Comment: I think this question will be more suited for http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a logic analyser with the ability to decode serial streams - it's a much more versatile tool in the end.  There are many of them - I've used the [Saleae Logic](https://www.saleae.com/), and an [Open Bench Logic Sniffer](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Open_Bench_Logic_Sniffer) to good effect in the past.

But I'm sure an Arduino *could* do it.

Comment: long term though is to leave it in the circuit to convert the commutation tracks- whatever would go in there would need to be capable of both reading it/extracting the bits to TTL outputs... a tiny arduino fits well and is dirt cheep... glad to hear you think the Arduino *could* do it too...I realize it wont have the power of a analyzer, but still, theres only 5 bits i need to manipulate if i recall correctly...